# Xamarin Forms: Single button that opens a dropdown menu

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hi does anybody knows if I can make a button in Xamarin Forms that opens a small dropdown menu? I did this in android studio but I can't find a way how this could work in Xamarin.

**It should look like this:**

[image: It should look like this]

**And like this if the button is clicked:**

[image: And like this if the button is clicked]

And the Button should not be in the navigation bar because this page don't have one.

So if anybody could help me I would be very grateful and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: A dirty workaround could be making the dropdown as popup and place it below the button with a relative layout and use the button to toggle visibility of the dropdown popup.

Comment: Might be a bit late but this might help out. https://github.com/SKLn-Rad/Xam.Plugin.PopupMenu

Answer (score 2):

The closest API in Xamarin that does that is to [display a pop-up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/pop-ups) using `DisplayActionSheet`, but the dropdown menu will be at the bottom of the screen. Or you can use a `Picker` ([link to documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/)).

If you want to implement something that look exactly like the image in your post, you can create a `StackLayout` that contains a few buttons, and show it when the drop down menu button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

i think that you can do it not directly but if we let some things be together we can achieve it, you have to add toolbar item for the button and for the menu list it's a popup page  that has transparent background and list menu on the top right !